# Service endpoint interface for python

Tags: java, web-services, python-3.x, service, endpoint

I am working on java in which eclipse gives some tools like wsimport which imports all the java files and class files by specifying the URL of the web service to the tool. Is there some thing like this for python? How do we work with python to use any web service. There should be some service endpoint interface for python right? If there is one, How do we use it? Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Jurko's port of suds](https://bitbucket.org/jurko/suds) will do the job. It's easy to use, and it exposes a web service's methods and object types.

Example:

```
>>> import suds
>>> from suds.client import Client
>>> client = Client('http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?WSDL')
>>> print(client)
Service ( Weather ) tns="http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/"
   Prefixes (1)
       ns0 = "http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/"
   Ports (2):
       (WeatherSoap)
          Methods (3):
             GetCityForecastByZIP(xs:string ZIP)
             GetCityWeatherByZIP(xs:string ZIP)
             GetWeatherInformation()
          Types (8):
             ArrayOfForecast
             ArrayOfWeatherDescription
             Forecast
             ForecastReturn
             POP
             WeatherDescription
             WeatherReturn
             temp
...
```

As you can see, the `Client` class just requires a URL in order to print out info for the web service.

```
>>> weather = client.service.GetCityWeatherByZIP('02118')
>>> print(weather)
(WeatherReturn){
   Success = True
   ResponseText = "City Found"
   State = "MA"
   City = "Boston"
   WeatherStationCity = "Boston"
   WeatherID = 14
   Description = "Cloudy"
   Temperature = "64"
   RelativeHumidity = "80"
   Wind = "S9"
   Pressure = "30.19F"
   Visibility = None
   WindChill = None
   Remarks = None
 }
```

The `client` object has a `service` attribute that lets you run methods. When I ran `GetCityWeatherByZIP`, `suds` converted the XML response into a Python object (in this case, a `WeatherReturn` object). You can access its attributes like any other Python object.

```
>>> weather.Description
Cloudy
>>> weather.Wind
S9
```

You can also create XML-associated objects of your own with `Client.factory`.

```
>>> forecast = client.factory.create('Forecast')
>>> forecast.WeatherID = 6
>>> print(forecast)
(Forecast){
   Date = None
   WeatherID = 6
   Desciption = None
   Temperatures = 
      (temp){
         MorningLow = None
         DaytimeHigh = None
      }
   ProbabilityOfPrecipiation = 
      (POP){
         Nighttime = None
         Daytime = None
      }
 }
```

Although it's a little dated, [this doc page](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation) should help you get started.